# Apple TV not showing up in Xcode > devices & simulators menu

Tags: xcode, tvos, apple-tv

I have an Apple TV 4k model. It is connected to a display and is powered on. Here are the steps I have tried to connect Apple TV to Xcode:

- use same wifi on both mac and Apple TV
- on Apple TV go to `Settings > Remotes and Devices > Remotes App and Devices` to see that Mac is not already paired
- on Xcode open `Window > devices & simulators` menu and wait for `Apple TV` to show up in `Discovered` panel on the left

Steps I have followed to troubleshoot:
- updated both Mac and Apple TV to latest OS versions
- reboot both devices
- turn off wifi and then turn on for both Apple TV and Mac
- make sure both devices are physically right next to each other

I'm unable to solve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: did you see this page? There is a Step 3. On Apple TV, navigate to Settings > Remotes and Devices > Remote App and Devices and keep your Apple TV at this screen. Im not in home to test.

Comment: https://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-wirelessly-connect-apple-tv-4k-to-xcode-on-mac/

Comment: That solution doesn't seem to work. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I have this problem too, still didn't find any solution but when I unpair apple tv it appears in devices window, after pair it disappear

Comment: turning wifi off and on again on my Mac made the Apple TV appear

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. I took all the steps but after the device connected in xCode it disappeared. However as @Caro said in the comments, turning off wifi on my mac and restarting it caused the device to reappear in xCode.

I did further testing and I think the answer given by @Claudio Castro applies after you have fully connected the device -- you need to *remain* on the **Remote Apps and Devices** screen (the one that shows your Mac) -- if you select the Device and go into that screen, the device will disappear from xCode.

Comment: By some magic, my ATV suddenly showed ... but as **locked**.  How do I unlock it?

Comment: I then **un**Locked it ... but now the error msg = **Failed to prepare device for development**. FWI, I have selected tvOS = 16.4

Comment: Found out I need to update Xcode to 14.3. Sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your Apple TV by "Set Up with iPhone" for some reason this will cause your Apple TV to not appear in Xcode Via Window > devices & simulators.

I had to reset from Apple tv from scratch and use the manual setup option which fixed my issue.